# Tap on one element triggering tap on another element appearing in the same place on mobile Safari (ghost taps)

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, html, mobile-safari

When someone taps a button, it causes another page to appear. To prevent the tap from cascading down into another element on the new page that appears, we use preventDefault. We have seen this as a solution to the problem elsewhere on StackOverflow. However, it's not working for us.

Code:

```
// Bind what happens when user taps on app
$( '#templates .app_box' ).on( 'tap', function( ev ) {
    // Get itunes ID
    APP_PICKED = $( this ).attr( 'itunes_id' );

    // If on category page, update category history with new path
    if ( panabee_get_active_page().attr('id') == 'category_page' ) {
        // Get app path and scrub app from it
        var app_path = $(this).attr( 'path' );
        app_path = app_path.substring( 0, app_path.lastIndexOf(PATH_DELIMITER) );

        // Convert path string into array and store in history
        CATEGORY_PICKED_HISTORY = get_path_array( app_path );
    }

    // Show app
    if ( playing_game() ) {
        play_app_game( this );
    } else {
        panabee_change_page( '#app_page' );
    }

    // Prevent double tap
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Reproduce:

1) From your iPhone, visit [www.tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com).

2) Tap on the first app icon. This causes the app page to appear. If you tap in the right place, the original tap causes the download button (on the app page) to get triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our problem was that we triggered the tap event with custom code. We fixed this by using jQuery Mobile (1.3.2) instead. It's bloated, but it works and handles all touch events like tap and swipe.

Comment: 1.3.1 was causing this conflict?

Comment: No, we rolled our own tap/swipe event handler, and it was causing this somehow (still unclear how). The problem vanished after using JQM.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is preventing the event *tap* to propagate.

However, it is most likely that some other event causes the trigger (guess: event *click*). In fact, your *tap* is not even a real DOM event, but something invented by jQuery Mobile framework, so it is very likely that it behaves differently compared to native JavaScript events.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Try binding *click* event instead.

Comment: click events preform terribly on mobile because they wait to see if there is a double click.  There is literally an 800ms delay on a click event in iOS - you probably don't want to bind to that.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [Fast Button](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) that faced a similar problem with mobile ghost clicks. They ended up implementing a *click buster*.

> "What we came up with to deal with these ghost clicks was called a
>   click buster. What we do is simply add a click event listener to the
>   body, listening on the capture phase. When our listener is invoked, we
>   try to determine if the click was as a result of a tap that we already
>   handled, and if so we call preventDefault and stopPropagation on it."

Answer (score 0):

What about ev.stopPropagation()? You need to stop bubbling to prevent other elements receiving the event.
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/